# PHP File Permissions and Running HTML Files as PHP

Tags: php, ftp, file-permissions

I am running a Linux server (a DV server with Media Temple). It's a pretty standard LAMP setup. I'm running PHP 7.4.

I'm using two programs to upload files to the server: Filezilla and a tool called [Codeanywhere](https://codeanywhere.com).

When I upload a PHP file using SFPT with Filezilla the permissions are `664`. When I create a PHP file with Codeanywhere the permissions are `644`. Notice they are slightly different! Both files work when visited in a browser.

I also have a line in my .htaccess that causes `.html` files to run as PHP:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml .html
```

When I upload an HTML file using SFPT with Filezilla the permissions are still `664`. When I create an HTML file with Codeanywhere the permissions are `644`.

However, the HTML uploaded using Filezilla gets an `Internal Server Error`.

Any idea why the HTML file with `644` permissions will run, but the HTML file with `664` permissions won't run. Also, any way to change the default permissions when files are uploaded using Filezilla?

Edit: Additional Information

I've checked the error logs and there are not errors logged related to this issue. The error the browser receives it this:

```
GET https://sample_domain.com/test.html 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

If I switch the permissions to '644' on the HTML file, then it works fine.

Comment: What I recommend is accessing the Apache log to see what triggered the "Internal Server Error" error, along with the code.
These errors log are usually located in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: I did check the error log. Nothing helpful in the log. Seems like the error does not register.

Comment: What is it in the log? Are you sure it's the correct log file?